# In R test if case is within a range of times and a unique ID

Tags: r, date, range

I have two data.frames with information.

The first one is the biggest, and contains a lot of rows for unique speed measurements in curves. So it has columns with a curveID, a datetime of the measurement, and a lot of columns with other speed and curve information.

The second one is a small database, containing known roadworks. It contains three columns: curveID, from and to. curveID has the same factors as the first database, from is a datetime (POSIXct) is the start roadworks on that roadworks on that section and to is a datetime (POSIXct) containing the end of roadworks.

Quite simplified the databases look like this:

```
speedmeasurements <- data.frame("curve_id" = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), "datetime" = c(0, 2, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 5))
roadworks <- data.frame("curve_id" = c(1, 1, 3), "from" = c(1, 5, 2), "to" = c(3, 7, 4))
```

I've added a column to create intervals, like this `roadworks$range <- interval(roadworks$from, roadworks$to)`

Now I want to add a column roadworks to my first database. This should be a logical value, which checks whether or not a speed measurement was done during roadworks. So, I need a bit of code which checks if the combination of curveID and datetime of the speed measurement are within roadworks timeslots.

In the simpified example, I would like to get this result:

```
speedmeasurements <- data.frame("curve_id" = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), "datetime" = c(0, 2, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 5), "roadworks" = c(F, T, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, T, F))
```

I've been thinking of an `ifelse()` like this:
`speedmeasurements$roadworks<- ifelse(speedmeasurements$curve_id == roadworks$curve_id & speedmeasurements$datetime %within% roadworks$range, T, F)`, but this seems to fail due to different object lengths.

Does anyone have a way forward? Perhaps a `data.table` solution, but I'm quite novice in that area.

Kind regards,

Johan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to do with by `curve_id`, it suggests a join operation. Unfortunately, base R's `merge` and `dplyr`'s `*_join` functions do not do inequality, so you'd be stuck with splitting by `curve_id`, doing some manual labor on each, and then rebinding them.

`data.table` allows "in-equi" joins (join on a *range*) directly.

I'll start by adding in the "roadworks" *column* so that we see something from the join.

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(speedmeasurements)
setDT(roadworks)

roadworks[,roadworks := TRUE]
roadworks
#    curve_id from to roadworks
# 1:        1    1  3      TRUE
# 2:        1    5  7      TRUE
# 3:        3    2  4      TRUE
```

And now the merge:

```r
roadworks[ speedmeasurements, on = .(curve_id, from <= datetime, to >= datetime) ]
#     curve_id from to roadworks
#  1:        1    0  0        NA
#  2:        1    2  2      TRUE
#  3:        1    8  8        NA
#  4:        1    9  9        NA
#  5:        2    1  1        NA
#  6:        2    2  2        NA
#  7:        2    3  3        NA
#  8:        2    4  4        NA
#  9:        2    5  5        NA
# 10:        3    1  1        NA
# 11:        3    3  3      TRUE
# 12:        3    5  5        NA
```

A few things from this:

- `data.table`'s merge premise is that `A[B, on=.(...)]` is effectively "B left join A" (see [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/6188334/3358272);
- it preserve's the joined column names from `A`, not `B`, so we will want to rename them
- those rows without a match get `NA`, which is expected.

Full code with cleanup:

```r
speed2 <- roadworks[ speedmeasurements, on = .(curve_id, from <= datetime, to >= datetime)
                    ][, to := NULL ][, roadworks := !is.na(roadworks) ]
setnames(speed2, "from", "datetime")
speed2
#     curve_id datetime roadworks
#  1:        1        0     FALSE
#  2:        1        2      TRUE
#  3:        1        8     FALSE
#  4:        1        9     FALSE
#  5:        2        1     FALSE
#  6:        2        2     FALSE
#  7:        2        3     FALSE
#  8:        2        4     FALSE
#  9:        2        5     FALSE
# 10:        3        1     FALSE
# 11:        3        3      TRUE
# 12:        3        5     FALSE
```

We can reduce the lines of code *slightly* with

```r
speed2 <- roadworks[ speedmeasurements, on = .(curve_id, from <= datetime, to >= datetime)
                    ][, c("datetime", "from", "to") := .(from, NULL, NULL) ][, roadworks := !is.na(roadworks) ]
```

For readability, I often use `magrittr::%>%` with `data.table` (though most often associate it with `dplyr`), resulting in this:

```r
library(magrittr)
speed2 <- roadworks[ speedmeasurements, on = .(curve_id, from <= datetime, to >= datetime) ] %>%
  .[, c("datetime", "from", "to") := .(from, NULL, NULL) ] %>%
  .[, roadworks := !is.na(roadworks) ]
```

(Note that `data.table` has a long-standing bug where if the last operation is an `:=` assignment, see https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-faq.html#why-do-i-have-to-type-dt-sometimes-twice-after-using-to-print-the-result-to-console)

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy answer!
Does the ```from <= datetime, to >= datetime``` work well on POSIXct though? I get na's only as a result after running the first line.

Comment: I use `<=` with `POSIXt` all the time, including within `data.table` non-equi joins, so it certainly can work. If you're getting `NA`s in the other columns, my first thought is that there were no overlaps found. Consider updating your question with representative data if you're still having problems.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I'm looking into it, but can't find it yet. Perhaps a time-zone issue...

Comment: I've been focussing on the datetimes, but my mistake was in the curve_id... Your solution works like a charm!